# FramedCloud appears disjointed

Tags: java, gwt, openlayers, gwt-openlayers

Using GWT OpenLayers, whenever I display a `FramedCloud`, the cloud appears disjointed. Meaning, the box inside the cloud which contains the data I am trying to display is shifted to the right so that the balloon looks strange. This is a simulation of how it looks:

```
(------------)
|              |
|              |
|              |
(------------)
             \
              .
```

As you can tell, the right side sticks out the `FramedCloud`.

```
String html = new String("<HTML><BODY><H1>" + dataPoint1 +
                         "<br />" + dataPoint2 +
                         "</H1><TABLE WIDTH=300><TR>" + dataPoint3 +
                         "</TR></TABLE></BODY></HTML>");

thePopup = new FramedCloud(String.valueOf(id),
                           lonLat,
                           new Size(10, 10),
                           html,
                           new Icon("", new Size(0, 0), new Pixel(0, 0)),
                           false);
```

I have tried removing the HTML, but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this had nothing to do with `gwt-openlayers`. It had to do with **OpenLayers 2.10** which I am using. The issue is with the cloud-popup-relative.png file missing two pixels. Downloading the new file as shown in the issue being tracked at the [osgeo.org](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/3413) site fixed my problem.